# Get result of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty basic website connected to a database and I want to access the result of an SQL query:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("Database") 
    or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT path FROM db1 WHERE id > 4");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
    echo $row->path;
}
```

On the website nothing shows, not even an error
(The SQL code works for sure)

Comment: check for errors against your query also, not just the connection

Comment: You're checking for errors after your connection, after selecting the database, but not after actually running the query. I would try that, even if you're sure the query works (you executed it successfully through phpmyadmin or workbench). There certainly are reasons that you wouldn't get an error trying to connect but would not be able to execute queries.

Comment: Or more succinctly, just do what @Fred-ii- said.

Comment: Yeah, @Don'tPanic mine was *"in a nutshell"* ;-)

Comment: I checked for errors against the query but there are no

Comment: what is the id column type?

Comment: the id column type is int

Comment: you should better use mysqli or PDO_mysql as your sql lib... mysql is deprecated

Comment: what about http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and try `mysql_select_db("Database", $connection)`

Comment: Yeah i know but for this project its ok @lpg

Comment: ask the guy who gave you an answer below then, I'll have to move on now. Good luck, sincerely.

Comment: ok... the code looks fine to me, so I would suggest looking to data or config issues... Is your table having id's greater than 4? Are you able to see other "echo" outputs in your webpage?

Comment: Yes i am able to see other echo outputs and my table has id's greater than 4

Comment: Ouu you are right there are no id's greater than 4 , with greater than 3 everything works. Sry my mistake :D

Comment: Therefore you could have just done `WHERE id >= 4` which means greater than or equal to 4 and you would have had results. This is what the real solution here is ;-) @Maximilian

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks to all for your efforts I feel sorry for making such an dumb mistake can someone please make an answer so i can accept it

Comment: You're welcome @Maximilian ;-) *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated in comments that there were no id greater than 4,

you could have just done `WHERE id >= 4` which means greater than or equal to 4 and you would have had results.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than-or-equal